# Redirect if domain is not correct

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect URLs with wrong domains to the correct domain.

Pseudo code example:

```
if (domain != "www.correctdomain.com")
    redirect("www.correctdomain.com")
```

How can I do this with a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this with an If directive...

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```

Or mod_rewrite. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: A note to clarify the accepted answer: You can only use the `<IF>` directive if you're running Apache 2.4.x

Comment: You can also include any  subdomain with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)example\.com [NC]`

Comment: What does the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$` directive do? If the HOST is not empty?

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft I wonder where that might be relevant. Maybe very old web client which does not include [Host header in HTTP request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)?

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574064/serverhttp-host-not-set covers a few conditions. One is a request to IP address - we do not wish to alter those. Other is internal apache internal dummy connections, or Options, and the like. So that line makes sure it's a normal request.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to make 301 redirect in SEO purposes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The comment about 301 is right, but the code is wrong.
This will redirect www.example.com to example.com.
The OP wants to redirect all which is not www.example.com to www.example.com...

Comment: Maybe this answer does not match the question from above. But it matches exactly my usecase :-) I want to redirect from www.example.com to example.com.