# Redirect all aliases to main domain

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I have multiple domains (**alias1.com, alias2.com, alias3.com**, ...) pointing to the same webspace for **maindomain.com**.
The alias domains are set as ServerAlias in the apache site config, maindomain.com is the ServerName. All Domains have Let's Encrypt SSL.

I want to redirect all requests to the main domain, so alias1.com/posts should be redirected to maindomain.com/posts.

Whats the best option to do that in apache config, .htaccess or laravel, and how do i do it?

Comment: Configuring this inside the `.htaccess` feels more appropriate to me.

Comment: yes, thats what i thought. but i dont want to add a redirect for every alias, since i have many and they can change over time. there should be a regexp for htaccess to redirect all other domains to maindomain.com, right?

Comment: Yup, take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20776712/281278).